# How to query all documents in one node by index with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index distributed over multiple nodes. My intention is to query all documents in each node separately.
i.e I need a call to extract documents from only one node.
Is that possible?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: I have an index distributed over 33 nodes and each time I ingest new data to the index I need to update the old data from that newly inserted data (modify some records). Thus fetching all index and updating in one server would take so long so I thought maybe updating each node separately would be more efficient.

Comment: you can move all the shards of that index to a single node and update it that way, but not one node at a time

Comment: but checking each newly inserted record against all documents in one computer is taking too long